# Stripe setup intent

Tags: javascript, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm looking to collect a customers card information then save it to charge later after they have consumed my service. I'm following the exact same steps on: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse but somehow I'm stuck on the error: **"Missing required param: payment_method_data[card]."**

My steps are as below:

- A customer creates an account and these details are saved to my database
- I create the customer on Stripe

```
    $stripe_customer = CustomerAlias::create([
        'email'       => $user->email,
        'description' => 'Subscriber',
        'name'        => $user->name,
        'phone'       => $user->phone,
    ]);
```

- I create a setup intent on Stripe

```
    public function createASetUpIntent($stripe_customer){
        $intent = \Stripe\SetupIntent::create([
            'customer' => $stripe_customer->id,
            'usage'                => 'off_session',
        ]);

        return $intent;
    }
```

- The card HTML

```
    <form id="setup-form" action="{{ route('completeCardSave') }}" method="post">
        <label class="pull-left">Enter your name as it exactly appears on the card</label>
        <input id="cardholder-name" type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform:uppercase">
        <input type="hidden" name="client_secret" id="client_secret" value="{{$client_secret}}">
        <br>
        <label class="pull-left">Enter your card number, expiry and CVC</label>
        <div id="card-element"></div>

        <button type="submit" style="color: #5533FF !important;" id="card-button">
            <span class="save_card_text_span"> Save Card </span>

        </button>
    </form>
    <div class="card_custom_errors">

    </div>
```

- The Javascript to mount the card and send to Stripe API to confirm intent

```
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_my_test_key_goes_here'); // UK

    // ADD ELEMENTS TO THE PAGE

    // Create an instance of Elements
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
    // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
    var style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
    };

    // Create an instance of the card Element.
    var card = elements.create('card', {
        hidePostalCode: true,
        style: style
    });

    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
    card.mount('#card-element');

    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
            displayError.textContent = '';
        }
    });

    var cardholderName = document.getElementById('cardholder-name');
    var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
    var clientSecret = document.getElementById('client_secret').value;
    var cardElement =  document.getElementById('card-element');

    cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    stripe.confirmCardSetup(
        clientSecret,
        {
            payment_method: {
                card: cardElement,
                billing_details: {
                    name: cardholderName.value,
                },
            },
        }
    ).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
            // Display error.message in your UI.
            $('.card_custom_errors').css({"display":"block", "color":"red"})
                .html("There was an issue saving your card, please contact us at: farmsuite@ujuzikilimo.com");
        } else {
            // The setup has succeeded. Display a success message.
            // Now we can submit the form, which will send an email to the user and redirect to a completion page
            // Submit the form

        }
    });
```

The issue here now is when I submit the form to confirm the intent, I'm ending up with the error: "Missing required param: payment_method_data[card]."

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm not sure what I'm getting wrong. 
I'd like to note that my test keys are correct so that's not the issue.

Comment: Going by the error, the problem seems to be with the card, right?  And yet you've shown us code for everything *except* collecting the card ... In the guide you linked to, are you doing step "4. Collect Card Details"?

Comment: Yes, step 4 is very much included I just didn't show the html part of it. That's what I meant by mounting a card using stripe.js.

Comment: Can you show us how you set `cardElement`? This all looks correct so it might be an issue with how you mounted the Stripe Element.

Comment: We can't help fix a puncture if you give us the entire car but not the tyre with the hole ... :-)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Hahaha. I've added the tyre. Both the HTML form and the JS mounting and sending the confirmation request to Stripe

Comment: @PaulAsjes I've edited the question to show how I'm setting the cardElement

Answer (score 1):

I think issue here is that you are creating the source but not passing any card details.you want to create a card token tok_XXX client-side first with Checkout or Elements and then pass that card token when creating the source server-side.

Comment: I had the token way before where I was charging on checkout then I scraped it to charge after service use. Let me try tokenizing the card information and passing that on customer creation I see how it goes.

Comment: I've tried with creating the Customer with the source token but still same error when I get to the part of confirming the Intent

Answer (score 1):

The issue was basically here on this variable:

```
    var cardElement =  document.getElementById('card-element');
```

I should propagate the initial declaration of the card variable which is this:

```
    var card = elements.create('card', {
        hidePostalCode: true,
        style: style
    });
```

and use that in the call to confirmCardSetup